# Map URLs not working for images. Looks like a subtle typo bug in the html output (Doxygen v1.8.20)

Tags: doxygen

I did some troubleshooting of the map URLs not being clickable in my html output.  I tracked it down to an extra 'a' prefixed to the value for the 'usemap' attribute.  (or a missing 'a' on the map name attribute; note how the 'a' is in the id attribute)

```
<div class="center"><img src="../../d2/d83/FILE.png" border="0" usemap="#aIDENTIFIER" alt=""/></div>
<map name="IDENTIFIER" id="aIDENTIFIER">
   <area ... />
   <area ... />
   <area ... />
</map>
```

Is this a bug?

(Doxygen 1.8.20)

Comment: Most likely this is a bug that has been fixed in the current master (some problems regarding this 'a' have been fixed), but due to the missing of a small MWE it is hard to tell. Furthermore you didn't specify which browser you used (probably Chrome as on FireFoix this problem did not surface but on Chrome it did. I'm not sure about Edge and Safari).

Comment: Yes, Chrome.  But because I found the issue in the HTML I don't see it as browser dependant.  (great if other browsers can connect the 'usemap' attribute to the map 'id', but the HTML spec says to use a map with a matching 'name' attribute).

Comment: The mentioning of the Chrome browser was just to see whether the problem might be similar to the ones fixed in master. As said before that without a small MWE it is hard to tell whether or not the problem has been solved in the doxygen master version. Did you try with the (self build) master version? Otherwise please provide a small MWE so it is possible to check whether or not the problem has been solved (images are used on multiple places so it might be another case).